# OpenDKIM Signing return fail when spaces in mail

Tags: unix, email, centos, postfix, dkim

Few days ago I install OpenDKIM Signing using on my CentOs 6 server by manual - http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/08/installing-opendkim-rpm-via-yum-with-postfix-or-sendmail-for-rhel-centos-fedora/.

But at all my my mails has

> dkim=neutral (bad format) header.i=@site.com

I did many tests and the problem are the spaces in the html code html editor, here two examples, the first is bad while the second good:

#

HTML SOURCE

```
<html><head></head><body>TEST
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<a href="http://%%unsubscribelink%%/">Unsubscribe me from this list</a>
</body></html>
```

REPORT auth-results@verifier.port25.com

---

### DKIM check details:

Result: **fail**

#

HTML SOURCE

```
<html><head></head><body>TEST<a href="http://%%unsubscribelink%%/">Unsubscribe me from this list</a></body></html>
```

REPORT auth-results@verifier.port25.com

---

### DKIM check details:

Result: **pass** (matches)

#

How can fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that is "spacing" issue??